# Small web app quick poor man's security for a page or two

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor Server app to create a very simple app where I want to secure a page or two with poor man security (keep the honest honest)

I was thinking in the razor component for the route something like this:

```
@page "/admin/code/1234"
```

where 1234 can come from appsettings.

How can I accomplish this in Blazor?

Comment: So, "security by obscurity" is sufficient, you say? How about `@page "/admin/code/{code}"` and check `code` against a value from appsettings?

Comment: Or, so you can have a fixed route, open a little popup for a "PIN" to be entered?

Comment: Great answers, is there a way to store the code on the local machine so users won’t have to enter it each time. If you want to add your answer I’ll mark it. Clients can be Windows, iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: [Browser storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#browser-storage-server)